# Woocommerce variable products not showing up correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing some issues on the woocommerce variable products.
I have a number of different variations for every products (around 4-5 per product). Even though I've already set them up in the variation settings, but on the front-end it still shows this message when the user selects it:
"Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination."

Would it be due to the large amount of combinations that is causing the variation to conflict with each other? 
Or is it due to the stock/weight limit settings, does anyone experience this in their project?

Comment: Does every variation have a price? If not, it is not purchasable.

Comment: yes there is price in every variation combination eg. A1 + B2 + C3 = USD 10.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solved this out. It turns out to be not an WordPress/Woocommerce problem but the hosting settings. What happens is the max_input_vars = 2000 isn't really enough for running huge amount of variables.

Refer here for this: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/

Just change the  max_input_vars = 2000 to a larger number & it should be working properly again. For my case I have to upload .user.ini for godaddy hosting.